# Passing ref via props in React to prevent duplication of commonly used functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a 5 different button components, all of which are styled very different from one another and require different props to render. One piece of functionality that I would like all 5 components to have is that after they have been clicked the button loses focus (using `.blur()`). I have a :focus style for accessibility reasons, but after a button is clicked I need to lose the :focus style.

Rather than me write the exact same functionality across all 5 buttons it makes sense for me to create a separate component to handle this functionality.

I'm new to React so haven't had to do anything like this before so would like to know the best way of tackling the problem as I have read that passing ref via props is a good way of identifying an anti-pattern, but with my current knowledge of React it seems to be the only way of achieving what I want.

If I were to do this inside of one of the Button components which is then rendered on a page it would look like this:

```
const Page = () => {
  const loseFocus = () => {
    this.btn.blur();
  };

  return (
    <Button
      onClick={loseFocus}
      ref={(btn) => { this.btn = btn; }}
    >
      Toggle
    </Button>
  );
};

const Button = props => (
  <button onClick={props.onClick}>
    {props.children}
  </button>
);
```

I don't want to have to do this for every Button component I ever include though, ideally I would have every button automatically lose focus after being clicked.

If I were to do something like this in jQuery I could just target all `.btn` elements (which is a common class shared by all 5 components) with an event listener like so:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
 $(this).blur(); 
};
```

I know I could do something very similar in plain javascript but would this be going against React best practice?

Answer (score 0):

In this case i would like to use little different tactics.   I build one button component 
with variable properties to fit all my needs aka

```
<Button type="large" text="cool" link={href}/>
```

and inside use

```
render()
{
   return  <div style={css}>button stuff</div>
}
```

where css is toggled per click or whatever i want .

there is real power if css per component is used
you can use javascript to control what css will bee for
current instance. even possible to make dynamic css mutations on component state changes etc ...